# Issues installing VS2015 and cordova

Tags: cordova, installation, visual-studio-2015

I´m trying to reinstall VS2015 professional, on windows10, and have several issues regarding hanging installation windows.

I decided to reinstall because at some point my cordova setup got broken, and not even cleaning the cache was working anymore.

At some point it seems that the process got stuck so I decided to force reinitialization of the PC.

In the end, I could have it "installed", but for some reason (maybe due to the installation issues), the new cordova project, that would trigger the installation of the cordova tools is not among the list of options (should have been at Installed -> Other Languages -> JavaScript -> Apache Cordova Tools but I dont have it)

My installation lies on a SSD drive (F:)... I´ve seen some threads pointing possible issues with this kind of installation on another driver, but I´m not able to change it anymore anyways.

Is there a way to manually install the Cordova Tools, since I have VS pretty much working for my needs?

Also, where to locate the logfiles to try to troubleshoot installation issues?

Please, help me this is very frustrating.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The default install doesn't include the Cordova tools. You need to go into the custom setup and select "Tools for Apache Cordova" in order to get them during the initial install.

However, there is a 'bread crumb' template inside the new project dialog that you can use to initiate the installation of the Cordova tools. Create a new project, go to Installed -> Other Languages -> JavaScript -> Apache Cordova Tools and select the "Tools for Apache Cordova" project. This should initiate vs setup and install the tools.

Comment: Hi Michael,

That "BreadCumb" template is exactly what I´m missing here

Comment: Interesting. That implies that VS thinks Cordova is already installed. Can you go to add / remove programs and uninstall it, then restart VS and see if the breadcrumb shows up?

Comment: Hi Michael, I got on that very odd scenario where the breadcumb menu is not present, neither the Cordova tools at program files.

I´m 200% sure I´ve selected it on installation.

I noticed also, that on the "confirmation Dialog" of the installation, the cordova tools would not show up regardless of selecting them.

Comment: I´m struggling for over 2 days now on it. trying to repair installation/ uninstalling and installing again, etc.

I don´t exactly how I got to that point, it was working here for me with some other bugs (ripple hanging sometimes, some plugins errors, etc), and that´s why I decided to reinstall the whole VS2015...

I manged to install it successfully on a notebook, following the same steps, but not on my desktop PC.

Now, all that I wish is a workaround that wouldn´t imply to format PC. Let me know which kind of information logs you´d need, I´ll be happy to provide them.

Comment: Also, FYI Typescript installation seems to get stuck everytime.
Windows SDK 90% of the time;

Answer (score 0):

I found what I was looking for.

Indiviudal instller of cordova tools is located here:

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudioSecondaryInstaller\14.0\installers\MDDJSV2\en\0

Then I could manage to install it doing the following:

1. Dowloading the ISO instead of the web-installer
2. Making sure to terminate several processes unrelated to the installation, especially those with high I/O access, such as GoogleDrive, OneNote, Dropbox, etc
3. Perform typical installation only
4. Install isolated cordova tools from the exe on that folder

After the installation, I was still having a weird problem whereas VS was crashing immediately after the initialization. Incredible as it seems, after several retries, I decided, randomly, to double click the splash scren and then, out of suddenly never had the issue again!

Still, typescript is missing here, and several other problems are arising, but now I have a startpoint